# How to get "Location permission " for always with setting page link pop up in flutter using location handler package in android 11?

Tags: flutter, android-permissions, android-location

I know that, in android 11, the permission seeking pop up/ alert dialog never offer "always" option, rather offer without it , like the photo bellow - [image]

Note that, this pop up offer a "setting link" with stating that you can turn on always from the setting.

I want this pop up in my flutter project too , but I failed!

I am using `permission_handler: ^8.1.1` , if I use

`await Permission.location.request()`
it offer me an pop up/ alert dialog like the photo bellow, but this is not what I want.

[image]

I am using a function to ask for always permission, but it never show any popup or dialog.

my code -

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    await Permission.locationAlways.request();
    print(Permission.locationAlways.status.then((value) => print(value)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

How to achieve the pop up like first photo?

AndroidMainfest.xml scenario -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to request for `Permission.locationWhenInUse` first before being able to request for `Permission.locationAlways` as mentioned in the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler).

> The locationAlways permission can not be requested directly, the user has to request the locationWhenInUse permission first. Accepting this permission by clicking on the 'Allow While Using App' gives the user the possibility to request the locationAlways permission. This will then bring up another permission popup asking you to Keep Only While Using or to Change To Always Allow.

Once Permission.locationWhenInUse has been granted, you can now request for locationAlways.

```dart
await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();

if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request().isGranted) {
  await Permission.locationAlways.request();
}
```

Calling `Permission.locationAlways.request()` should display this Location Permission Settings.

[image: Android Location Permission Settings]